# I just moved to bootstrap and its css is strict. how do I change nav hover to quit bouncing and resize my p element?

Tags: html, css

I just moved to bootstrap to make my website responsive. During creating it, my nav when I hover over it it bounces and makes the header nav move instead of just hovering and showing my border-top effect. As well as that, I cannot figure out how to resize header font-size and the

. My site is https://affattraction.com

You can see the issues there. Under the showcase h1 there is black text on the left that is not resizing (

) issue.

Also while hovering over the nav links the links bounce down a bit and they should stay still. The only indication of hover should be the green bar which is working perfectly.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please post your code for hover

Comment: I don't speak for the whole community, obviously, but I am always hesitant to click away to a mystery domain somebody posted in their question.  Are you able to recreate this issue in a snippet, or JSFiddle or Codepen?

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Comment: Sorry for posting a link, I was in a hurry, I had to go somewhere and wanted to get this resolved. Any help is appreciated as I always include in my posts.

Answer (score -1):

You can add border-top if you plan to have border-top for hover

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    padding-top: 15px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border-top: transparent 2px solid;
}
```